# Devise how to support CURL -u user:pwd Authentication?

Tags: curl, devise

My application used Devise, and API want to support cURL to test like [BaseCamp API](https://github.com/37signals/bcx-api#making-a-request)

```
curl -u username:password https://app.com/api/v1/test.json
```

I know how to use token to authentication,but I want to use **-u username:password** to authentication and return json directly.How to implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This nothing to do with Devise, Rails is easy to do HTTP Basic and Digest authentication.[HttpAuthentication](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic.html)

```
curl -u username:password https://app.com/api/v1/test.json
```

The username and password can pass to the 'u','p' param in the following code:

```
user = authenticate_with_http_basic { |u, p| User.authenticate(u, p) }
```